# What does a CIDR mask mean in the context of "ip address add"?

Tags: linux-networking, ip-address, cidr

I'm attempting to learn to set up Wireguard properly (not just by copy-pasting). I've come across this line on the [quickstart](https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart) page:

```bash
ip address add dev wg0 192.168.2.1/24
```

Reading the man page for `ip`, it appears that `address add` assigns the given address to the given device. That makes sense, except that the example address includes a CIDR mask. I'm struggling to wrap my head around what this means in this context and my google-fu is failing me.

Are we saying we want the address to be `192.168.2.0`, or... I don't even know. What else could it mean?

**EDIT:** Wait, I just realised this could be a way of specifying the subnet. Maybe this is obvious to Linux people but I'm a Windows guy and in the Windows GUI you specify subnet mask separately to IP. I'll leave this question here though in case I'm wrong.

Comment: This is not Linux specific. CIDR masks are used in Windows as well. For example, run `netsh interface ipv4 show config` in a Windows command prompt.

Comment: The mask explains to the host what is on the same network vs. what is off the network and needs to be sent to a gateway.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I know, but you don't normally configure Windows interfaces through the command line, you do it through the GUI and in that case the subnet mask is specified in `255.255.255.0` notation separately from the IP itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `ip address add dev wg0 192.168.2.1/24`

That adds the IP address 192.168.2.1 to the indicated interface, with a subnet mask of /24 or 255.255.255.0. The possible IP addresses for wg clients are 192.168.2.2 through 192.168.2.254.

Essentially, the /24 defines the maximum number of clients that may connect simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks! This is the most straightforward answer so you get the points :)

Comment: The main benefit of CIDR notation is, when you can specify the subnet mask with just two digits, why bother with more than 10 keystrokes for `255.255.255.0`?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, this is the UNIX/Linux (and probably other operating systems) to define with one record IP address and netmask. The decoding is:

```
192.168.2.1/24
```

This is the IP address

```
192.168.2.1
```

This define the number of constant bits of IP address:

```
24
```

For example if its `16` you have constant `192.168` and the rest is variable.

Comment: I understand what a CIDR mask is, I just couldn't understand what it meant in the context of setting the IP of an adapter. I guess it's also setting the subnet mask at the same time. Is there a way to set the subnet separately, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Clonkex, the other way I know is `192.168.2.1/255.255.255.0`. But this is not exactly separate way. If you use `ifconfig` you can use separate `netmask` definition.

Comment: @Clonkex that's correct. Note that an adapter can have more than one IP address in different subnets with different subnet masks.

Answer (score 1):

CIDR denotes the subnet mask.   Most of the people find it difficult to work with CIDR values unless it's a round number like 8,16,24,32.

You can use [this website to get a better understanding](https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html)

Many network admins use this.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it all, and I built [an IP calculator for both IPv4 and IPv6](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX) for the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

In IPv4, you have:

- Addresses, which are 32-bit identifiers, usually represented in the "dotted quad" representation, like `192.168.1.2`.
- Networks, which are a range of IP addresses, and are defined by a start address and a netmask.

The netmask is used as a 32-bit value, but its binary representation will always starts with 0 or more `1` bits, and the rest will be `0` bits.

Being a 32-bit value like an IP address, it used to be the norm to represent netmasks like IP addresses, using the "dotted-quad" notation, like `255.255.240.0`.

But this is a lot of data to type when there are only 33 possible values (see below), and more recently people just give the number of "1" bits, also called the "prefix length".

`255.255.240.0` in binary is `11111111 11111111 11110000 00000000`, i.e. 20 `1` bits and 12 `0` bits.

So instead of using the pretty long `255.255.240.0` notation, only will just give the prefix-length: `20`.

The prefix-length is usually appended to the end of the start IP address, separated by a `/`.

So the following are different representations of the same network:

- `10.1.16.0 netmask 255.255.240.0` (start address + netmask)
- `10.1.16.0/20` (start address + prefix length)
- `10.1.16.0 - 10.1.31.255` (start and end addresses)

An IP address, *per se*, does not have a subnet mask or prefix length, but to configure an interface you need to define not only the IP address, but also the network (as this is required to know which other addresses are on the same network, or need to be sent to the gateway for further routing).

Given the subnet mask (or prefix length) and the IP address, one can find the network (just "AND" the binary representation of the IP address and the subnet mask, and you'll get the starting IP).

So:

- `192.168.2.1/24`
- `192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0`

both mean:

- The IP address is `192.168.2.1`
- The network is `192.168.2.0/24`, also known as `192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0`, also known as the `192.168.2.0 - 192.168.2.255` range.

Here are the equivalents between prefix lengths and netmasks, and the associated network size:

```
/0  0.0.0.0         the whole IP address space, over 4 billion values
/1  128.0.0.0       half of it, over 2 billion values
/2  192.0.0.0       half again, over 1 billion values
/3  224.0.0.0       over 536 million
/4  240.0.0.0       over 268 million
/5  248.0.0.0       over 134 million
/6  252.0.0.0       over 67 million
/7  254.0.0.0       over 33 million
/8  255.0.0.0       over 16 million
/9  255.128.0.0     over 8 million
/10 255.192.0.0     over 4 million
/11 255.224.0.0     over 2 million
/12 255.240.0.0     over 1 million
/13 255.248.0.0     524288
/14 255.252.0.0     262144
/15 255.254.0.0     131072
/16 255.255.0.0     65536
/17 255.255.128.0   32768
/18 255.255.192.0   16384
/19 255.255.224.0   8192
/20 255.255.240.0   4096
/21 255.255.248.0   2048
/22 255.255.252.0   1024
/23 255.255.254.0   512
/24 255.255.255.0   256
/25 255.255.255.128 128
/26 255.255.255.192 64
/27 255.255.255.224 32
/28 255.255.255.240 16
/29 255.255.255.248 8
/30 255.255.255.252 4
/31 255.255.255.254 2
/32 255.255.255.255 1
```

Note that on an Ethernet LAN (and some other similar networks), the first and last address of a network are reserved.

/31s are a special case used for point-to-point links on routers which support it.

/32s designate a single IP address, so they have specific use-cases (anycast, router IDs in networks using unnumbered interfaces...).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit concerning when you don't know what CIDR is when trying to configure wireguard. CIDR is a term in ip subnetting, and refers to the basics of ip subnetting.
CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing) notation rather than the common subnet mask 255.x.x.x when configuring addresses and networks.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

The CIDR notation combines the IP address and the subnet mask into a single concise format. The format is represented as follows:`IP_address/Prefix_Length`.
IP_address: This is the specific IP address.

Prefix_Length: This indicates the number of bits set to 1 in the subnet mask. It determines the size of the network and the number of available IP addresses within that network.

For example, consider the CIDR notation "192.168.1.0/24":

- **The IP address is "192.168.1.0."**
- **The prefix length is "/24**," which means the first 24 bits are used for the network portion, leaving 8 bits for individual host
  addresses within that network.

So, in this example, the CIDR notation "192.168.1.0/24" represents a network with IP addresses ranging from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255, where the last octet (8 bits) is available for host addresses.

I would recommend to watch a basic ip networking course/basic ip subnetting on YouTube, especially when configuring wireguard, so you understand the basics that are the foundation of a vpn and wireguard
https://youtu.be/CMdkW3agFn0?si=SX_hKoTDbwerxfSI

Edit:
In terms of the add command, it has logic to translate a cidr mask to a proper network adapter config, or logic to translate a config with cidr mask to a proper ip address assignment for an interface.

Comment: What makes you think I don't know what CIDR is? I know what it is. I just didn't realise you set IP and subnet mask at the same time with that command so it made no sense to me to include the CIDR in the IP. I've spent my entire life setting adapter IPs through the Windows GUI, where IP and subnet mask are specified separately. It was a mental leap to realise `ip address add` was setting both at the same time, even though it seems obvious now. I was stuck thinking along the lines of adding multiple IPs at once from the range defined by the CIDR part, even though that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Because you asked a question about CIDR. If you knew what it was then I would have suspected another sort of question

Comment: I realise the title and some wording was potentially misleading. I've updated it to better reflect my intent. I guess I just thought it was obvious I knew what CIDR notation was in general, just not how it applied to this specific command. Hopefully the tweaks I made make this clearer.